# Liferay 7 Web Content Display - web content in Global site is not available

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Recently none of the web content in the global site is showing up when selecting the web content in a web content display.  Nor does the search find the particular web content I'm trying to use.

I assume it is an index issue, but I've reindexed everything I could think of that would be related - everything journal article related as well as document lib related - but nothing has worked.  Restarting Liferay hasn't helped, nor has re-publishing the web content.  Permissions are unchanged.

Any ideas?  Can anyone tell me which indexing option *should* work?

Liferay 7 GA7

Thanks.

Comment: In case the problem is in the elasticsearch index: 
(1) Try manually deleting the Elasticsearch index from your Elasticsearch server using a curl DELETE command (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html ) and after that, execute a full reindex.
(2) You can also try using https://web.liferay.com/en/marketplace/-/mp/application/70121999 to check the index status

Comment: Please carry this over to the [Liferay community](https://liferay.dev/). It doesn't involve any programming problem, so it's off topic on stackoverflow. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Olaf Kock My apologies.  I wasn't aware of what constituted "on topic" until reading the info at the link provided.